# How to correctly implement Amplify to Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, aws-amplify

for the last few days, I was trying to figure out how to fix the issues I was having with Amplify for Flutter: `error: compiling for iOS 9.0, but module 'Starscream' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 11.0` and `Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:amplify_core/amplify_core.dart'`

Things I tried:

1. Following the tutorial of the doc https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/flutter. That resulted in: `project directory/ios/Pods/AppSyncRealTimeClient/AppSyncRealTimeClient/Connection/AppSyncConnection/AppSyncSubscriptionConnection+ErrorHandler.swift:9:8: error: compiling for iOS 9.0, but module 'Starscream' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 11.0: project directory/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Starscream/Starscream.framework/Modules/Starscream.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule` and `Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code note: Using new build system note: Building targets in parallel note: Planning build note: Contructing build description`.
   I uncommented the line `platform :ios, '9.0'` on Podfile and changed it to `platform :ios, '11.0'`, while also changing the development target to 11 on the projects xcworkspace. The same error happened.
2. Following the tutorial of the doc https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-flutter-app-amplify/. That resulted in:`Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:amplify_core/amplify_core.dart'` when I tried to import the core. Like that, I couldn't use the Amplify() class.
3. Restarting the computer.
4. Deleting the Amplify folder.
5. Running `amplify uninstall`, and trying from the start again.
6. Searching other posts on this and other websites.
7. Running `amplify clean`.

Things to note:

1. The Amplify installation, init, and configure steps returned no errors.
2. If I delete the Amplify dependencies `amplify_flutter: '<1.0.0' amplify_auth_cognito: '<1.0.0' amplify_analytics_pinpoint: '<1.0.0'` the app runs on the simulator just fine. As soon as I put them back the errors return.

Comment: For the first error what fixed it for me was to go into the ios directory and in the Podfile  change "platform ios:" To a higher deployment like 12 maybe. As for the second problem I'm currently having it too and not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change `import 'package:amplify_core/amplify_core.dart'` to `import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify.dart';` then when you add your plugins you'll wanna do it like this `Amplify.addPlugins([authPlugin, storage]);`

I also ran `flutter upgrade` before I did this as well just make sure you save all your changes. You can find more information in there example flutter app

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: Okay I'm definitely confused now cause after making the changes you suggested, the same `compiling for iOS 9.0, but module 'Starscream'` error happened, but with @seanbrhn3 comment, I realized that if I changed the platform to iOS 12, the error returned `has a minimum deployment target of iOS 12.0`. The same thing with iOS 13 happened, so I tried with iOS 9, and it worked. Not sure why though, but I'll accept your answer for now, and if anything changes, I'll let you guys know. Thanks a lot, really helped.

Comment: Please note that Amplify Flutter requires a minimum iOS target of 11.0. Refer: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/flutter#prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

If you are following this tutorial https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/flutter

then in the step of dependencies there is a correction:
https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/flutter#add-amplify-to-your-application

it should be like this :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:

  amplify_flutter: <1.0.0
  amplify_datastore: <1.0.0
  amplify_api: <1.0.0
  amplify_auth_cognito: <1.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Then just run:

flutter clean

flutter pub get

Comment: It should not be under dev_dependencies